# How to debug try and catch blocks?

Tags: java, try-catch, throw, catch-block

I was wondering if there is someone that can help me out with these two debugging assignments in Java, involving try/catch/throw statements. I can't seem to figure out how to debug either assignment working in NetBeans Zip file is attached.

All or any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Assignment 1:

```
package debugmeone;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
/*
 * This file requires debugging.  This is a partial file to read a text file
 * with simple error checking.  If the file is not found (you are testing this)
 * a FileNotFoundException should be thrown.  The second catch statement is
 * producing an error (red stop sign).  Why?  Your job is to have both
 * Exception and FileNotFoundException in this file.  Do not remove either one
 * of them.  Don't create the file accountrecords.txt; you are testing for
 * a file not found condition so there is no need to create the file.
 *
 * The output should be:
 *
 *   run:
 *   Error - File Not Found: accountrecords.txt
 *   Java Result: 100
 *   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
 */

public class ReadTextFile {

    private Scanner input;  // Ignore the hint given by NetBeans

    public void openFile() {
        try
        {
            input = new Scanner( new File("accountrecords.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Something bad just happened here.");
            System.exit(707);
        }
        // Debug this line; what should you do to solve this error message?
        //   Carefully read the error message provided by the IDE
        catch( FileNotFoundException  fnfe)
        {
            System.out.println("Error - File Not Found: accountrecords.txt");
            System.exit(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Assignment 2:

```
package debugmetwo;

/*
* You will need to debug this file.
*
* The output should be:
*
*  run:
*  There is a problem with the Eagle!
*  Java Result: 9999
*  BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
*/
public class ThrowEagleExceptionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
         EagleLanding();
        } catch (EagleLandingException badEagle) {
            System.out.printf("%s\n", badEagle.getMessage());
            System.exit(9999);
        }
    }

    private static void EagleLanding {
         EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, do you have a specific question?  What have you tried?  Exactly what problem(s) did you encounter?  SUGGESTION: 1) Find a Netbeans debugger tutorial (like [this](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cmurphy/summer2008/1007/netbeans/7_debugging.html)), 2) Open your code in the debugger, 3) Set a breakpoint in `main()`, 4) Trace your code in the debugger. 5) Trace both "success" and "error" code paths.

Comment: Your post not describe a what problem you have...

Comment: In your ReadTextFile class, the openFile method will never go into the FileNotFoundException catch block.

Comment: @Michael Markidis: 1) The OP needs to learn to ask more precise questions than a vague "help me debug this", 2) He should be encouraged to learn his IDE's debugger: sooner than later, 3) It doesn't really help him if you just "give him the answer".  IMHO...

Comment: Agree with @paulsm4 . You should ask more precise questions rather than asking for help for your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You have a compile time error message, not a runtime one which is what a debugger is for. The message to read is

```
    // Debug this line; what should you do to solve this error message?
    //   Carefully read the error message provided by the IDE
    catch( FileNotFoundException  fnfe)
```

You are expected to read the error message provided in the IDE and fix it. Hint: the most specific exception have to come first.

You second example won't compile either. You need to make it compile by throwing the exception. If you don't know how to do that, look at an example.